# How do I calculate the percentage of difference between two images using Python and OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to write a program in Python (with OpenCV) that compares 2 images, shows the difference between them, and then informs the user of the percentage of difference between the images.  I have already made it so it generates a .jpg showing the difference, but I can't figure out how to make it calculate a percentage.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a simple idea you can adapt. But always ensure the images being compared are of the same shape.

**Code:**

```
img1 = cv2.imread('dog.jpg', 0)
img2 = cv2.imread('cat.jpg', 0)

#--- take the absolute difference of the images ---
res = cv2.absdiff(img1, img2)

#--- convert the result to integer type ---
res = res.astype(np.uint8)

#--- find percentage difference based on the number of pixels that are not zero ---
percentage = (np.count_nonzero(res) * 100)/ res.size
```

- If `img1` and `img2` are similar most of the pixels in `res` would be `0` resulting in a lower percentage.
- If `img1` and `img2` are different this percentage would be higher.

*Note:* I have shown an example solution for single-channel images. However, the same can be extended for multi-channel images.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to calculate this on your own. You will need the count of diferent pixels and the size of your original image then a simple math: `(diferentPixelsCount / (mainImage.width * mainImage.height))*100`